# what is the advantage of a c++ class having static methods with exact same signature as the interface methods

Tags: c++, static-methods, virtual-functions

What is the advantage of defining static methods with exact same signature as the interface method in the class which implements it .

```
class IInterface
{
public:
  virtual void fn()=0;
}

class Impl :IInterface
{
public:
  ~Impl();
  static  void fn();
}

Impl::~Impl{
}

Impl::fn(){
 //do something
}
```

Comment: Where have you seen this? In your example, `Impl` is still an abstract class, because it never overrode `IInterface::fn`.

Comment: See this in a 3rd party library . basically 'Impl' is a wrapper . The static implementaion of Impl::fn acutlly calls the libray method  ex:  Impl::fn() {  :: fn() }  . I guess , the interface is to support for Mock tesing . if then how it will be useful ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no advantage of having such `static` method. `static` methods don't override `virtual` methods (which are always non-`static`).

In fact it has **disadvantage**, that you **cannot implement the actual** method to override the base method. Because one cannot have same method signature in a single `class` (one `static` and another non-`static`).

```
class Impl :IInterface
{
public :
~Impl();
staic void fn();
void fn() {} // error: invalid (can't have same signature)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no advantage.

Your derived class `Impl` still is as an **Abstract class** since it **does'nt & can't** override the pure virtual function. You cannot create any objects of it.

A static function cannot override a virtual function from Base class because dynamic polymorphism uses the `this` to evaluate the function call at run time, while static functions do not pass the `this` pointer, because they are not specific to any object.